# using glVertex2d(); in LWJGL

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I'm pretty new to LWJGL and I have been messing with some tutorials and following them to learn the library so I can eventually start making games. I'm having a problem with my glVertex2d() code as no matter what values I put in the brackets it will always display a box the same size on the program.

The world size is 640x480 and I have no idea what the problem could be

public static void drawBackground() {

```
  // Sky
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);

  glColor3d(0.7,0.8,0.9);
  glVertex2d(0, 0);
  glVertex2d(640,0);

  glColor3d(0.5,0.6,0.8);
  glVertex2d(640, 480);
  glVertex2d(0, 480);



  // ground

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);

  glColor3d(0.5,0,0);
  glVertex2d(0,0);
  glVertex2d(640, 0);

  glVertex2d(640,32);
  glVertex2d(0, 32);

  glEnd();
```

}

will post the complete code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Straight away I can see you are not closing the drawing of the sky, that might be confusing OpenGL when you go to draw the floor. Also as you are meaning to draw two separate objects you'll need to define them as separate by pushing in a new transform matrix for it before drawing, then taking the matrix out when you're finished with it (unless you want the floor to be parented to the sky..).

```
public static void drawBackground() {
   // Sky
   glpushMatrix();
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0.7f,0.8f,0.9f);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(640,0);
    glColor3f(0.5f,0.6f,0.8f);
    glVertex2f(640, 480);
    glVertex2f(0, 480);
   glEnd();
   glpopMatrix();

   // ground
   glpushMatrix();
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0.5f,0,0);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(640, 0);
    glVertex2f(640,32);
    glVertex2f(0, 32);
   glEnd();
   glpopMatrix();
}
```

Sorry I can't test this code as I don't have a blank LWJGL context ready.
I have also changed glVertext2d to 2f because you're not in need to double-point precision, and appended an "f" to the end of floats, this is a way of telling Java that a hardcoded number is a float - Java assumes Integer by default (so would round up).

Comment: Hey thanks I tried this but now it just prints a blank screen instead. I had it printing with the original code just it wasn't to the correct size

Comment: The problem may lie with your camera or rendering modes also, I'd always suggest starting any 3D project with 3 axis arrows at origin and ensuring the camera can see them (like 3D modeling programs do). It will give you a visual reference do where you are and what angle you're looking at as well as object size.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer to exactly your question, but...
This is `immediate mode` rendering (easy to spot in code if you see a method call `glBegin(...)`). There are 2 things that you should know about it for sure: it's deprecated, and it's inefficient. Don't use it. Instead I would recommend http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ or any other not-very-old tutorial on OpenGL.